# How to call Rest webservice in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have @RestController in my web application, I want to make use of this service in my Authentication provider for security purpose .Could you please advise how we will achieve this? ( FYI : I am using Spring boot)

For example my REST Service url is : http://localhost:8080/authentication.json
Login page url : http://localhost:8080/login

My question is similar like following question, but difference is, REST Service available in the same application . So i hope  REST Template or HTTPUrl connection is not required ? Please advise. 
 
[spring security login with rest web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828344/spring-security-login-with-rest-web-service).

Given below is sample code snippet.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("authorize")
public AuthorizeController{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json")
    public Employee authorize(@RequestParam String username) {
         return employee;
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationProvider provider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);                
    }
}

public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {           
       // Here i need to call REST Service . which is present in the same application.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to use Basic Authentication or OAuth?

Comment: Basic authentication only

Comment: So just need something like this: http://www.sothawo.com/2015/07/build-a-spring-boot-rest-service-with-basic-authentication-for-several-users/

Comment: When you want to call other beans in the same application just inject them (@Autowired) - there's no need for a HTTP call and no need for auth.